# On what criteria does a kernel deems a process unresponsive? What stratergy does it uses to detect such process?

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-14.04, kill, freeze

In ubuntu (am using 14.04) while executing certain programs or applications, the window turns greyscale and darker. When I googled I found that it can happen when a program becomes unresponsive. Is it correct? If yes, on what basis a program is deemed to be unresponsive? What stratergy is adopted to make this decision?

Sometimes after a while these processes are killed and sometimes they are not. Why does this happen?

Comment: I'm not a Linux user however on Windows, if the message loop for a Win32 process is held-up, it'll be deemed "unresponsive" until it has been completed.